# import data from google spreadsheet into html as a number

Tags: html, css, google-apps-script, spreadsheet

Can anyone tell me how I can pull a total from a Google Spreadsheet into a website?
We are looking at taking a fundraising total from the spreadsheet and displaying it with HTML and CSS goodness as a thermometer. There is no DB or CMS on the site, nor do we want to give the financial guys access to the HTML to make changes... 
Many thanks
Tim

Answer (score 0):

You can do it using Google Apps Script. It's easy to fetch the data in any the Google Spreadsheet, then deploy the script as the developer with access to anyone, and share the desired value using [ContentServices](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/content/content-service).

Lastly, on your website you can do a AJAX call to your Apps Script deployed URL and show it on the page.